# Can I get a little help debugging this regex?

Tags: php, regex, youtube

Here's the error I get `preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 77`

And here's the business:

```
$youtubeIdPattern = "#(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^\"&\n]+|(?<=??(?:v|i)=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+#";
                $youtubeIdMatch = array();
                if ( isset( $regexMatch[0] ) && $regexMatch[0] != "" ) :
                    preg_match($youtubeIdPattern,$regexMatch[0],$youtubeIdMatch);
                endif;
```

FYI, we're trying to grab just the video ID from a Youtube URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you've got 2 question marks in a row `(?=??(?` -- do you mean for that to be a literal question mark  (`\?`) ?

Comment: That is exactly what was wrong with it. Escaped the ? and it worked. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `??`, Bryan!

`?` needs to be escaped if you want to match a literal `?`.